# Xamarin override resources

Tags: android, xamarin

I am currently in the process of porting my Apps from Android to Xamarin.

first my current situation:
I got a Android Library Project included in serveral Apps. The Library Project has some config options in string.xml for example a server url.
Since every App that is using the Library has it's own server I override the server-url in strings.xml in every app.
Now the Question:
Is there a way in Xamarin to do the same there: Having a string in a Shared-Project that is being overwritten bei the App-Project itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well it should work exactly in the same way as with eclipse, but that would be a really easy check to make.

Comment: No, Xamarin works totally different.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same needs I used the following approach:

Writing an MSbuild script that 
1) Makes a copy of my solution folders 
2) Overwrite the files (or folders) I need to change (Resources, Assets, Properties, Shared Projects files... 
3) Compile the Android Project (.csproj file) of the solution I copied.

At the end it was easier than what I thought, I don't have to make any change manually to the proj files and through the script I can directly build and install into the device different versions.